# JSF 2.0 custom components with XSLT

Tags: jsf, custom-controls, jsf-2, xslt

Is it possible to write own JSF 2.0 components with help of XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you couldn't write an XSLT translation from your xml into xhtml facelets.  You might have a bit of trouble mapping the backing beans and other expression language across the transformation.  You should be able to automate the transform on a web request with an appropriate servlet filter.

Another approach might be to go the other way around.  Presumably you want to use XSLT, because you have XML files to generate other view technologies.  Well JSF is supposed to be view agnostic, so you could write JSF Renderers to rnder your facelet views into your other view components.  JBoss Seam does this for PDF and MS Excel.